# Elasticsearch - Query field against aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am exploring the ease of querying and aggregating the data using elasticsearch. But i am not able to pivot and aggregate the data in a single query as below:

Considering the data:

[image]

Is there a way to query the below result
that pivots and aggregates the value as below:

[image]

Required Result:

```
{  
   {  
      "A":a1,
      "B":b1,
      "Value":3
   },
   {  
      "A":a1,
      "B":b2,
      "Value":3
   },
   {  
      "A":a2,
      "B":b2,
      "Value":4
   },
   {  
      "A":a1,
      "B":b3,
      "Value":11
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can nest two `terms` aggregations for `A` and `B`, like this, and you'll get exactly the results you expect:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "A": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "A"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "B": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "B"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "value_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "Value1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val. It worked exactly. Just had to add a label to the Sum.